# Не пойму почему else if не работает?

Tags: java, if

Не пойму почему else if не работает и почему компилятор требует указать w? Я же в самом начале прописал String w

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=0;
        String m;
        int a;
        String w;
         Scanner wm = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("man?");
         m = wm.nextLine();
         System.out.println("woman?");
         w = wm.nextLine();
          if (m == "man"){
          i++;
          a =i;}
          System.out.println("You fit!");
      } else if( w =="woman") {
          System.out.print("You dont fit"); }
        else{
           System.out.println("Thank you for your time.");
}






}
```

Comment: Мне кажется, или Вы несколько напутали закрывающие фигурные скобки? Вы уверены, что такая скобка нужна здесь: `a =i;}` ? Потому что при такой расстановке скобка перед `else if` закрывает вот это: `public static void main(String[] args) {`

Comment: Понял, спасибо)